# when a web app generate most markup by javascript ...

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have seen a web app that generate most of a page's markup by javascript+ jquery. The server only generate a web page with just 1 DIV . The rest are done with create on client side via javascript+jquery+AJAX .

What are the pros and cons of this javascript centric approach ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pros:

You get a lot of flexibility when your entire front-end is in javascript. Everything is generated dynamically and it's easier to load data on demand. It also makes it easier to bind elements to data, which allows them to update automatically as things change on the server (without requiring the user to reload their browser!). Check out Backbone.js or Knockout.js for interesting approaches to building heavy javascript apps.

Going this route also allows you to keep your server very light weight. Typically, the server just has to implement a simple RESTful/JSON interface. In practice, the frontend is a single static file and it makes calls to your interface. Since you're doing these calls asynchronously while the user is on the site, it can feel much faster and more like a native app (i.e. GMail)

Another nice perk is that having the client side do more work can often decrease the load on your server. The client won't even notice the extra work, since it happens so fast, but your server might appreciate the savings. You'll also potentially use less bandwidth if you're smart about your server calls.

Cons:

Some people have javascript disabled (although in practice it's a fraction of a percent of users). Also, browser cross-compatibility can be more difficult in some edge cases (but jQuery makes this much more tolerable). The biggest con is that many web crawlers won't crawl anything on your site because crawlers generally don't execute javascript. They just parse html (Google might be an exception here?).

In my experience with building web apps, any public facing content (i.e. marketing material) should be static content so that web crawlers see it. Once the user logs into the app, I like everything to be 100% client-side with RESTful calls to my server.

Answer (score 2):

Always aim to separate concerns:

- Information in markup
- Style in CSS
- Behavior in Javascript

If you start doing everything in Javascript alone, you break that model. And the model's worked pretty well for the web so far.

That being said, *do* use javascript for progressive enhancement of a site. E.g. if you can display something via ajax instead a page reload, then go ahead, but a normal page request should also still work.

Check out github's repository browser for a great example of progressive enhancement. If you're using a brower that supports it, it'll load pages via ajax, *and* change the url in the address bar to match. Otherwise, it'll do what it's always done, and simply go to the page with a normal link. So there's javascript in there, and does some cool tricks, but everything works without it.

Comment: +1 for mentioning github's repository browser. I almost used it as an example, and it is a really good example of progressive enhancement. I wonder if all services could be so fluid, though.

Answer (score 1):

- Con: very large javascript file
- Con: if javascript turned off your site does not work
- Con: harder to style
- Con: large javascript file returned to client with potentially more
  code than is needed
- Con: possibly difficult to debug

What if your interface returns large lists, do you need to return that also and loop through that in JS and build your controls and add them?

Comment: This, and the fact that your source code is public.

Comment: Wasn't me. My upvote is still there. Not sure why someone would downvote since you've pretty much covered all the points. Edit: Okay, I guess why someone might've downvoted is you didn't cover the pros as requested in the original question.

Comment: i just wish ppl would comment on downvotes kwim?

Comment: "Very large javascript" is probably no larger than the corresponding HTML and images compressed and minified, and almost no sites work without javascript; it's a phantom requirement poor software developers will put on others because of something they heard in 1995. Even modern screenreaders can get through javascript-heavy sites if you do it right.

"More code than is needed". What does that even MEAN? Difficult to debug? I'm not sure you understand what you're saying.

Comment: i'm guessing @Stefan downvoted

Comment: I accept the "large js file".  valid point.  in my experiance js is more difficult to debug than say c# or even vb.net.  if you have all the code in js which builds your ui, what if you are not going to include some controls?  the js still has the code to create those controls even if it's not called.

Comment: The large js file should be pros because browsers can cache them. Doing entire site with js, would require using MVC javascript framework like backbone.js. Otherwise like you said it would be really difficult to debug or handle at all. How its harder to style because you can just give classes to elements like normal?

Comment: @Pehmolelu: You're getting at the real point. Anything is hard to debug if you write it poorly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're not exactly being quite clear when you say "generated from javascript with jquery+ajax". That could mean that flat HTML pages are just being loaded in, as opposed to requiring a browser refresh. There's no right or wrong way to structure dynamic versus static HTML; everything has to be taken in context.

[jquerymobile](http://jquerymobile.com) uses this technique quite extensively.

Answer (score 1):

The server should do the heavily lifting because that's what it is there for. The involvement of the client should me minimal. Client side development should focus on enhancing the UX and making sure things work nicely on many browsers. It should not be about tasks like restructuring the DOM to be a certain way, sorting and filtering through data, and so on - unless there is a compelling reason.

So offloading too much of the presentation logic on the client is probably a bad idea, in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You are contrasting

```
 Server produces data (usually JSON) -> Client-side Java Script creates HTML
 Server produces data, server formats HTML -> Client renders HTML
```

An application can use some combination of those techniques, the former makes it easy to give dynamically updating pages with a rich user experience. You will notice that the former also offloads more work to the client (I assume that JSON is more terse than the resulting HTML) and hence in the long-term once the JavaScript is downloaded and cached the network bandwidth is reduced.

The JavaScript-centric approach is more complex and typically needs more effort to write.

Comment: the example I saw is almost 100% of the former/top approach you mentioned.

Comment: There is value in uniformity. If all your data is exposed as JSON services and you are fluent in javaScript with a nicely understood framework the extra overhead of doing everything in JavaScript is not that high and the resulting UI may be very nice.